# Edit .pack file in android studio / eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a build box project's android deployment code and inside that having .pack files so from that files i want to modify the .pack file but i'm not able to edit that .pack file

is there any way to edit .pack file from android studio?

[I have read this but may be there is anyway or someone knows](https://www.buildbox.com/forum/index.php?threads/how-to-open-pack-file-in-android-studio-project.12409/)

> When i open .pack file in studio it looks like

[image]

any help appreciating.

Comment: You can check this out: https://community.arm.com/tools/f/discussions/5824/how-to-open-a-pack-file

Comment: When i try to rename .pack to .txt or .zip getting same issue while unzip